# Get value from input field while typing, using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, integer

I am trying to set 2 variables with values from input fields and use them to calculate area.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <label for="fname">Height:</label>
  <input type="text" id="boxHeight" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Width:</label>
  <input type="text" id="boxWidth" name="lname"><br><br> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//var l = jQuery('#boxWidth').find('input');   ---> does not work
//var h = jQuery('#boxHeight').find('input');   ---> does not work
var l = document.getElementById("#boxWidth");
var h = document.getElementById("#boxHeight");

var a = parseInt(l);
$(document).on("change paste keyup", "#boxWidth, #boxHeight", () => {
                console.log("text "+a);
            });
```

The code can be tested here [get input to integer](https://jsfiddle.net/58L1xhyo/2/)

Nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Nothing seems to work" is pretty vague. 'Why do I always get "text NaN"' would be a much more useful question. getElementById does not expect the pound before the id. You can't find an input inside #boxWidth because #boxWidth is an input. just get the value of it. Use a lot more console logs, or use the step by step debugger that modern browsers ship with to identify problems like `l` and `h` are both null.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of small issues getting the right input, and the value from those inputs.

```
$(document).on("change paste keyup", "#boxLatime, #boxInaltime", () => {
  var boxLatime = document.getElementById("boxLatime");
  var boxInaltime = document.getElementById("boxInaltime");
  var l = parseInt(boxLatime.value) || 0;
  var h = parseInt(boxInaltime.value) || 0;
  vr_do_l_h(l, h);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dvtc9brq/